# How to change image type to JPG in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

convert png image to JPG

Here is my code:

```
const uploadFile = ({ file, options }) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const orignalname = file.hapi.filename;
    const filename = `${moment().unix()}${generateCode(2)}${path.extname(
      orignalname
    )}`;
    const location = `${dirName}${options.dest}/${filename}`;

    checkOrCreateDir(dirName);
    checkOrCreateDir(`${dirName}${options.dest}`);

    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(location);

    file.on("error", err => {
      reject(err);
    });

    file.pipe(fileStream);

    file.on("end", err => {
      const fileDetails = {
        fieldname: filename,
        originalname: file.hapi.filename,
        filename,
        mimetype: file.hapi.headers["content-type"],
        destination: `${options.dest}`,
        path: location,
        buffer: file._data
        // size: fs.statSync(location).size
      };
      resolve(fileDetails);
    });
  });
```

I also tried **easyImage** and **imagemagic** package in node but can't got perfect output
Also using **imageThumbnail** package for thumbnail image

any type of image type to convert **jpg** format

Comment: "_can't got perfect output_" What kind of output you're getting? Notice, that jpg is a lossy image storing technique, if you're saving an image with just few colors and sharp edges as a jpg, the image always becomes more or less blurry.

Comment: I am getting image format as it is .png!!!  But not getting .jpg format of image type
EX: If I choose .png format Image so it format would be change into .jpg